# MtouchArch to RuntimeIdentifiers in MAUI ios

Tags: maui

I am migrating xamarin forms project to .net maui.as part of migration i am changing the iOS .csproj.

I have changed the MtouchArch to RuntimeIdentifiers as mentioned in the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/apple-projects#convert-to-runtimeidentifier

i have replaced i386, x86_64 to iossimulator-x86,iossimulator-x64 as mentioned in the above link.

after doing changes i am getting below error while restoring nuget pacakges after deleting bin and obj.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.304/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(90,5) : error NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'iossimulator-x64,iossimulator-x86' is not recognized.

below is my configuration in iOS .csproj in xamarin :

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugUAT|iPhoneSimulator' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>__UNIFIED__;__MOBILE__;__IOS__;__UNIFIED__;__MOBILE__;__IOS__;DEBUG;DISABLE_PINNING</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
    <DeviceSpecificBuild>true</DeviceSpecificBuild>
    <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
    <MtouchFastDev>true</MtouchFastDev>
    <MtouchFloat32>true</MtouchFloat32>
    <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
    <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
    <MtouchArch>i386, x86_64</MtouchArch>
    <MtouchHttpClientHandler>NSUrlSessionHandler</MtouchHttpClientHandler>
    <MtouchTlsProvider>Default</MtouchTlsProvider>
    <MtouchExtraArgs>-cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -framework Security -framework AudioToolbox -liconv -lc++" --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView -warnaserror:1503</MtouchExtraArgs>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <CodesignProvision>
    </CodesignProvision>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

below is my configuration in iOS .csproj in MAUI :

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugUAT|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>iossimulator-x86,iossimulator-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <DefineConstants>__UNIFIED__;__MOBILE__;__IOS__;DEBUG;MOCK_API</DefineConstants>
    <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
    <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Debug</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
    <DeviceSpecificBuild>true</DeviceSpecificBuild>
    <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
    <MtouchFastDev>true</MtouchFastDev>
    <MtouchFloat32>true</MtouchFloat32>
    <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
    <MtouchHttpClientHandler>NSUrlSessionHandler</MtouchHttpClientHandler>
    <MtouchTlsProvider>Default</MtouchTlsProvider>
    <MtouchExtraArgs>-cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -framework Security -framework AudioToolbox -liconv -lc++" --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView -warnaserror:1503</MtouchExtraArgs>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <CodesignProvision>
    </CodesignProvision>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Maybe create a new maui project to experiment with, and try to change csproj indirectly, via project / properties? See what runtimeidentifiers you can get that way? Maybe there is some bug in the doc. Could it want semicolon rather than comma? Just guessing.

Comment: in new maui project we dont have runtimeidentifiers. my project is multi project. new maui project is a single project.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "c# ios application" project. Anyway, I see that RIDs are not set by default. I've researched, and added an answer. NOTE: This build property is only needed if you have runtime-specific assets that must get added to project. (I mention this just for other people who may stumble on this Q&A; since you were using MTouchArch, you probably do have such assets. Many developers won't need to set this property.)

Answer (score 0):

That document is mistaken.

Separate with a semicolon `;` not a comma `,`.

See [MSBuild Properties / RuntimeIdentifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#runtimeidentifiers):

> The RuntimeIdentifiers property lets you specify a semicolon-delimited list of runtime identifiers (RIDs) for the project. Use this property if you need to publish for multiple runtimes.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64;ubuntu.16.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In your case:

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifiers>iossimulator-x86;iossimulator-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

FYI, complete list of possible identifiers is in:
[runtime.json](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/src/runtime.json).

Comment: i have tried with semicolon also. still getting error as /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk/7.0.86/targets/Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.targets(9,9): Error MSB3371: The file "obj/DebugUAT/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-x86/mauiimage.stamp" cannot be created. Could not find a part of the path '/Users/shirishasiddamshetti/MAUI_9june/LibraryTestAppMaui/App/Platform/iOS/obj/DebugUAT/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-x86/mauiimage.stamp'. (MSB3371) (Vanquis.Mobile.Platform.iOS).

Comment: one more info i want to give. i am using third party ios xcframeworks. 
using objective sharpie i am using these xcframeworks. 
in .xcframeworks folder having folders like  ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator, ios-arm64 and info.plist which is having info about these 2 architectures. 
for  ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator SupportedArchitectures array are listed like below.
<array>
    <string>arm64</string>
    <string>x86_64</string>
   </array>.
but i am giving RuntimeIdentifier as <RuntimeIdentifiers>iossimulator-x64,iossimulator-x86</RuntimeIdentifiers>.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what else to do. If you remove `RuntimeIdentifiers` completely, what error do you get?